# Midpoint Ellipse Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, graphics, ellipse

I am trying to write a program to allow a user to draw an ellipse by using clicks. The user left-clicks at first to select the radius, then right-clicks to select the horizontal radius, then right-clicks again to select the vertical radius. Nothing is drawn after clicking. I don't understand where the error is.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Ellipse extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

    Graphics P;

    public Ellipse()
    {
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    static int Radius = 0;
    int CenterX, CenterY, RadiusX, RadiusY;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        P=g;
        EllipseMidpoint(CenterX, CenterY, RadiusX, RadiusY);
    }

    public void EllipseMidpoint(int Cx, int Cy, int Rx, int Ry)
    {
         int Rx2 = Rx * Rx;
         int Ry2 = Ry * Ry;
         int twoRx2 = 2 * Rx2;
         int twoRy2 = 2 * Ry2;
         int x = 0;
         int y = Ry;
         int p;
         int px= 0;
         int py = twoRx2 * y;
         PlotEllipsePoint(Cx, Cy, x, y);

         //Region 1
         p = (int)(Ry2 - (Rx2 * Ry) + (0.25 + Rx2));
         while (px < py)
         {
             x = x + 1;
             px = twoRy2 + px;
             if (p < 0)
             {
                 p = Ry2 + px + p;
             }
             else 
             {
                 y = y - 1;
                 py = twoRx2 - py;
                 p = Ry2 + px - py + p;
             }
             PlotEllipsePoint(Cx, Cy, x, y);   
         }

         //Region2 
         p = (int)(Ry2 * (x + 0.5) * (x + 0.5) + Rx2 * (y - 1) * (y - 1) - Rx2 * Ry2);
         while (y > 0)
         {
             y = y - 1;
             py = twoRx2 - py;
             if (p > 0)
             {
                 p = Rx2 - py + p;
             }
             else
             {
                 x = x + 1;
                 px = twoRy2 + px;
                 p = Rx2 + px - py + p;
             }
             PlotEllipsePoint(Cx, Cy, x, y);    
         }         
    }   

    public void PlotEllipsePoint(int CX, int CY, int X, int Y)
    {
     drawPixel(CX + X, CY + Y);
     drawPixel(CX - X, CY + Y);
     drawPixel(CX + X, CY - Y);
     drawPixel(CX - X, CY - Y);
    }

    public void drawPixel(int x, int y)
    {
        P.fillOval(x, y, 5, 5);
     } 

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
        {
            CenterX = e.getX();
            CenterY = e.getY();
        }
        else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
        {
            Radius = Radius + 1;
            if (Radius == 1)
            {
                RadiusX = (int) Math.pow((Math.pow((e.getX() - CenterX), 2) + Math.pow((e.getY() - CenterY), 2)), 0.5);
            }
            else if (Radius == 2)
            {
                RadiusY = (int) Math.pow((Math.pow((e.getX() - CenterX), 2) + Math.pow((e.getY() - CenterY), 2)), 0.5);
            }
            PlotEllipsePoint(CenterX, CenterY, RadiusX, RadiusY);
        }
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            JFrame JF = new JFrame("Ellipse");
            JF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            JF.setSize(500,500);
            Ellipse E = new Ellipse();
            JF.getContentPane().add(E);
            JF.setVisible(true);
        }

     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
     public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: have you considered trying to debug it?

Comment: step debuggers were created for a reason ...

Answer (score 0):

Three things immediately jump out...

1. You should be calling `super.paintComponent` before doing any custom painting (and there is no need for `paintComponent` to be `public`), see [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details
2. NEVER, EVER maintain a reference to the graphics context, you want something painted, you make a request to the repaint manager and you wait until one of your paint methods is called. Painting is controlled by the repaint manager an repaints may occur at any time, most of the time without yout knowledge or interaction.
3. You never call `repaint` to ask the repaint manager to repaint your component...At the end of your `mousePressed` method, call `repaint()`...

Comment: Well, your x and y radius values are been (as near as I can tell) been updated correctly, the the only thing I can think off is there's something wrong with the way you are rendering it...Try feeding it you own known values and run a debugger over it...